# Which way is better to concatenate strings in python?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

```
def email_list(domains):
emails = []
for domain, users in domains.items():
  for user in users:
    emails.append(user + "@" + domain) # emails.append("{}@{}".format(user, domain))
return(emails)
```

Which way is better in this case and why?

1. emails.append(user + "@" + domain)
2. emails.append("{}@{}".format(user, domain))

Comment: an f-string would be even better `f"{user}@{domain}"`

Comment: What's your definition of "better"?

Comment: Read [PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)

Comment: @Fildor idk, which way is most often used by experienced developers?

Comment: The definition of "better" changes depending on your purpose. Is your software performance-critical? Do you want it to be easy to read? Do you want to be able to concatenate items that are not strings? In any case, I'd say the current most pythonic way of building a string the way you need it in your code is with the fstring `f'{user}@{domain}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my honest opinion, f-strings are the best. They are flexible and readable. Unlike other concats, you don't have to make sure you insert all strings. Infact, you can do something like that:

```
number = 9
text = "hello"
print(f"{text} {number}")
```

Also, it will automatically convert eventual quotes and special characters!

Globally, there isn't a solution better than another. It's all depending on the use case. But generally, fstrings are better.

Comment: _"Globally, there isn't a solution better than another."_ vs _"But generally, fstrings are better."_ ;D (thumbsup)

Comment: yeah that's pretty conflictual, i just wanted to say that the classic " "+" " has some sense, but most of the times fstrings do i better. It's all about the complicity (more execute time) of the concatenation and the nature of the concatenation

Comment: Thank you! Is there any "bad" way that you exactly shouldn't use in 2022?

Comment: @MarcoFragDelleMonache No worries, I got what you meant to say. Just made me chuckle a little bit.

Comment: yeah i laughed too when i have read it

Comment: @ДаниилДорофеев i think the fstring would be overkill if you have to concatenate only one variable to one fixed string. for example, if you had your email and a fixed domain, username + "@gmail.com" would be fine, because you are pretty sure you don't have particular values and special characters. but this matters only if your computer is pretty hold. in terms of assembly level, an fstring takes more time.. but in real terms, it's just some microseconds more. just always focus on code readability. it's very important for your code to be understood by anyone!